# Exercicio calculo maior numero python

Tags: python

Boa tarde,

Estou desenvolvendo um exercício em *python*, vi que já existem algumas resoluções semelhantes no forum, mas desenvolvi uma própria e não estou entendendo o motivo do mal funcionamento (só é retornado o valor 0, a não ser que caia no `if <2`, nesse caso a resposta é "ERRO")

Segue código e proposta do exercício, agradeço a ajuda.

Escreva a função maior_primo que recebe um número inteiro maior ou igual a 2 como parâmetro e devolve o maior número primo menor ou igual ao número passado à função

Note que:

> ```
> maior_primo(100) deve devolver 97
> maior_primo(7) deve devolver 7
> ```

```
def eprimo(k):

  n = 2
  numero = 0

  if k<2:
    return "Teste: Não é possivel calcular"
  else:
    while n<=k:
      if all(n%x!=0 for x in range(2,k)):
        numero=n
        n=n+1
      else:
        n=n+1

  return numero

k=int(input("numero k:"))

print(eprimo(k))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

na sua verificação de 1 a 1, você está procurando divisores até o número máximo dado(k), não até o número menor que está verificando (n):

```
if all(n%x!=0 for x in range(2,k)):
```

Troque por:

```
if all(n%x!=0 for x in range(2,n)):
```

e deve funcionar.

Depois de arrumar, fica um pouco de espaço pra você otimizar a coisa: por que começar procurando os primos a partir do número mais baixo, por exemplo? Será que teria algum ganho se você começasse de K e fosse verificando os números progressivamente menores?

Também veja se você entende direito o que essa linha que precisa de correção está fazendo - ela é código bem mais avançado do que o código que você tem em volta - se não estiver entendendo, é mais legal re-escrever de uma forma mais simples, que você entenda, do que usar uma fórmula mágica que "mais ou menos funciona".

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Fiz a correção e funcionou normalmente, entendi que caso mantivesse o range entre 2 e k ele seria bem maior, mas ainda penso que mesmo com esse range maior ele ainda deveria encontrar as divisões com resto 0 e consequentemente memorizar o número, não deveria?

Comment: o problema com o range maior é que ele vai passar por "n" também, e o resto da divisão de n por n sempre é zero, mesmo se n for primo.

Comment: Não conhecia essa diretiva `all()` com essa compreensão de lista. Python sempre me surpreende com sua elegância